# Unexpected emoticons/smileyes in output C++ USACO

Tags: c++, string, output

I'm trying to solve the following problem from USACO and my code produces the correct output, but it prints emoticons/symbols instead of actual numbers.  That is, instead of printing 1, it prints "Alt+1"=☺. I'm using CodeBlocks IDE.

Problem:
 Palindromes are numbers that read the same forwards as backwards. The number 12321 is a typical palindrome.

Given a number base B (2 <= B <= 20 base 10), print all the integers N (1 <= N <= 300 base 10) such that the square of N is palindromic when expressed in base B; also print the value of that palindromic square. Use the letters 'A', 'B', and so on to represent the digits 10, 11, and so on.

Print both the number and its square in base B.
INPUT FORMAT
A single line with B, the base 
SAMPLE INPUT

10

OUTPUT FORMAT
Lines with two integers represented in base B. The first integer is the number whose square is palindromic; the second integer is the square itself.
SAMPLE OUTPUT

1 1

2 4

3 9

11 121

22 484

26 676

101 10201

111 12321

121 14641

202 40804

212 44944

264 69696

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
bool palindrome(string input)
{
    string reversed = string ( input.rbegin(), input.rend() );
    if(reversed==input)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
string base(int square, int B)
{
    string output="";

            while(square>0)
            {
               int remainder = square % B;
                square /= B;
                if (remainder > 9)
                        output+=char('A'  + remainder - 10);
                else
                    output+=remainder;

            }
        return string(output.rbegin(), output.rend() );

 //convert number to another base
}
int main()
{
    int B;
cin>>B;

for(int i = 1; i <= 300; i++)
{
    int square=i*i;
    string base1= base(square, B);
    if(palindrome(base1)==true)
       cout<<i<<" "<<base1<<"\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What were the results of your debugging efforts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You convert digits above 9 to characters in a controlled fashion, but leave the conversion of 0 through 9 to the language – meaning you do add the characters with ASCII codes 0 through 9.

Instead of

```
output += remainder;
```

try

```
output += '0' + remainder;
```

Then, in the next step, I’d stringly suggest to rewrite both branches not to rely on the contiguous order of numbers and letters in the underlying encoding. What’s wrong with having a static translation string instead?

```
output += character[remainder];
```